# How can I create a three layer drop down menu?

Tags: html, css

Basically the title. I have the code to create one layer of drop down menu. How can I create more layer (here: third one)? My main goal is to make a multilayer drop down menu on a blogger website. I am pretty sure my HTML formatting is correct (I tried it on online editors) but am stumped on the CSS part.

CSS

```
/* Styles the first link in your menu */
.tabs-inner .section:first-child ul {
margin-top: -1px;
border: none;
}

/* Styles the overall navigation bar */
.tabs-inner .widget ul {
background: #000000;
border: none;
text-align: center;
}
/* Styles the individual links */
.tabs-inner .widget li a {
font: 12px Arvo;
border: none;
color: #ffffff;
}
/* Styles the links when hovered over */
.tabs-inner .widget li.selected a, .tabs-inner .widget li a:hover {
color: #333333;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
}


#navigationbar {
width: 200%; /* change the width of the navigation bar */
height: 20px; /* change the height of the navigation bar */
}

#navigationcss { 
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0; 
}

#navigationcss ul { 
float: none; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
overflow: visible; 
}

#navigationcss li a, #navigationcss li a:link, #navigationcss li a:visited {
color: #ffffff; /* change color of the main links */
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 25px;  /* change the first number for the top/bottom spacing, and the second number for left/right spacing */
}

#navigationcss li a:hover, #navigationcss li a:active {
color: #E74C3C ; /* change the color of the links when hovered over */
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 25px; /* make sure these are the same as the section above! */
}

#navigationcss li li a, #navigationcss li li a:link, #navigationcss li li a:visited {
background: #ffffff;  /* change the background color of the drop down box */
width: 150px;
color: #000000; /* change the color of the drop down links */
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 7px; /* similar to above, change for the spacing around the links */
}

#navigationcss li li a:hover, #navigationcss li li a:active {
background: #E74C3C ; /* change the background color of drop down items on hover */
color: #ffffff; /* change the color of drop down links on hover */
padding: 7px 7px;  /* keep these the same as the above section */
}

#navigationcss li {
float: none; 
display: inline-block; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}

#navigationcss li ul { 
z-index: 9999; 
position: absolute; 
left: -999em; 
height: auto; 
width: 150px; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navigationcss li:hover ul, #navigationcss li li:hover ul, #navigationcss li li li:hover ul, #navigationcss li.sfhover ul, #navigationcss li li.sfhover ul, #navigationcss li li li.sfhover ul { 
left: auto; 
}
```

HTML

```
<!--Start Navigation --> 
<div id="navigationbar">
<ul id='navigationcss'>
<li><a href="LINK">HOME</a></li> 
<li><a href=“LINK”>NOVELS</a>
<ul>
       <li><a href=“LINK”>INDONESIAN</a></li>
       <li><a href=“LINK”>PORTUGUESE</a></li>
           <ul>
                    <li><a href=‘LINK’>PORTUGUESE NOVEL NAME</a></li>
           </ul>
</ul>
</li>
</div>   
<!--End Navigation -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified a lot of the styling (and added an extra layer) to try and highlight a repeatable pattern you can use to construct nested menus in a programmatic way. Something to remember is that direct children of a `ul` should always be a `li`.

This essentially works by specifiying which `li` elements contain a nested `ul` element and assigning them a `.sub` class. Then use that class to target and shift `.sub ul` elements to the right by 100% of the width of the `li` it belongs to.

Also, using the direct descendent selector - `>` - we can write a rule so that every hovered `menu` class will only display the `ul` directly below it.

I'm using a `p` tag to style the text content of each `li` so that it is decoupled from the layout logic.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
}

.top-row {
  display: flex;
}

.menu > ul {
  display: none;
}

.menu:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu.sub {
  position: relative;
}

.menu.sub ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-row">
    <li><p>HOME</p></li>
    <li class="menu">
      <p>NOVELS</p>
      <ul>
        <li><p>INDONESIAN</p></li>
        <li class="menu sub">
          <p>PORTUGESE</p>
          <ul>
            <li><p>NOVEL1</p></li>
            <li class="menu sub">
              <p>NOVEL2</p>
              <ul>
                <li><p>CHAPTER1</p></li>
                <li><p>CHAPTER2</p></li>
                <li><p>CHAPTER3</p></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

/* Displays the dropdown menu on hover. */
li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: none;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

.main-navigation li ul li {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Front End Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Resets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ajax</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">WordPress Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Custom Post Types</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```